# How do I set cell fill to transparent/no fill

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwings

How I can set the cell fill to transparent using xlwings? I understand that `xl.range(XX).color = (r,g,b)` can be used to set the color, but is there a specific command for no fill? I would still like to see the cell boundaries.

Comment: To get no fill in VBA you'd typically use `rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone`

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, he's not asking about VBA. He's trying to use a python library (xlwings). The question you've referenced as a duplicate doesn't apply, IMO.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the python library xlwings, not VBA.

Comment: Sorry about that - somehow I'd gotten the idea that xlWings was a wrapper around the "native" VBA methods - not the case as you note.

Comment: `Range('A2').color = None` according to http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=color#xlwings.Range.color

Answer (score 0):

If you set `color` to `None`, the background colour of your range will be transparent.

```
import xlwings as xw

# Connect to the Excel file
wb = xw.Book(EXCEL_FILENAME)
sht = wb.sheets[EXCEL_SHEETNAME]
sht.range('A1:C10').color = None
```